# Filtering elements in a table based on relation with same table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, query-optimization

I have a `facilities` table. The columns are `id` (primary), `sector` (int) and `located_in` (nullable, references `id` on same table).

Most of the time, the `located_in` column is NULL, but in some cases, `facilities` can be located inside of other `facilities`.

In cases where this happens, I want the parent facility to **not be part of the results** (so removed).

A facility can only be located in another facility that is NOT also located in another, so this doesn't go *n* levels deep.

Dataset ([View on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92651c/1/0)):

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | sector | located_in |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      2 | NULL       |
|  2 |      2 | NULL       |
|  3 |      4 | NULL       |
|  4 |      1 | NULL       |
|  5 |      5 | NULL       |
|  6 |      2 | 2          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Query ([View on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92651c/1/0)):

```
SELECT * FROM facilities WHERE sector = 2;
```

Expected Result ([View on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92651c/1/0)):

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | sector | located_in |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      2 | NULL       |
|  6 |      2 | 2          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Actual Result ([View on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92651c/1/0)):

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | sector | located_in |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      2 | NULL       |
|  2 |      2 | NULL       |
|  6 |      2 | 2          |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.* 
FROM facilities f
LEFT JOIN facilities f2
  ON f.id = f2.located_in
WHERE f.sector = 2
  AND f2.ID IS NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8d3221a2ab927db0bbebbcbed4464f4)**

Comment: No luck trying to put it inside the bigger query where it should be, [have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530651/filtering-elements-in-a-table-based-on-relation-with-same-table#comment99646620_56530777) :)

Comment: @JeffWhite Please post full SQLFiddle demo so I could reproduce it

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery, that checks for any children of a location.

```
SELECT *
       FROM facilities f1
       WHERE f1.sector = 2
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM facilities  f2
                                    WHERE f2.sector = f1.sector
                                          AND f2.located_in = f1.id);
```

Maybe you want to remove the condition on equal sectors if cross sector relationships should also count.

Comment: Great start, thank you! There's only one little problem, the facilities table is joined with another table (providers) and when I'm running this, it deletes all the entries of that facility, to all providers.

My full query below:

Comment: SELECT ...
FROM providers p 
JOIN providers_facilities_pivot pf 
 ON p.id = pf.provider_id
JOIN facilities f 
 ON pf.facility_id = f.id
 AND f.sector = 1
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM facilities fs WHERE fs.sector = f.sector AND fs.located_in = f.id)
ORDER BY p.id;

Comment: Providers are connected to multiple facilities. With the data in my DB, if one provider has the exact facilities as in my OP (the 3, where one of them should be removed), then it correctly removes it from him, but from others as well, even if they don't have the same arrangement => Meaning that some provider can be connected just to facility IDs 2 and 1, but ID 2 still gets deleted for him because of another provider.

Comment: I hope what I wrote what somewhat clear.. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @JeffWhite: You should post a new question and fully disclose the complete situation there.

Comment: I think I could solve this if you had any tips or places to point me to. Maybe it's too much but thank you for your help till now!

Comment: Hey sticky bit, maybe this would make it a lot easier to see what I'm talking about? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42b21e/7/0

Answer (score 0):

This is a semidifference. My preferred SQL formulation:

```
select *
from facilities
where sector = 2
  and id not in (select located_in from facilities where located_in is not null);
```

Comment: Hey Jon, thank you for helping out man! I asked this question since it was needed in a bigger query that I'm still struggling with. All the queries here suffer from the same issue, they remove the facility for everyone in the list. Maybe you could find the issue? [Here's what I'm talking about.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542067/removing-specific-items-but-only-for-some-columns)